# Dell 5558 is preloaded with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: dell

Guys please tell me where I find the recovery disk for my Dell 5558 laptop I had ubuntu 14.04sp1?

Comment: http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso but you can also use 16.04 or 16.10.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [Dell maintains the Dell Ubuntu Images](http://www.dell.com/support/article/de/de/debsdt1/SLN265886/en), not Canonical.